# Check for interactive whiteboard or projector

Tags: c++, projector, whiteboard

I want to check that there is an interactive whiteboard or projecttor attached to the system. Actually I would like to check it is not there. (To be able to make different license levels.)
Is there any technique which could be sure?

Platform: MS Windows XP/Vista, MS Visual C++

Comment: Which Operating System(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Platform: MS Windows XP/Vista, MS Visual C++

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in standard C++ - you'll need platform specific libraries. For us to help you with that we'll need more info about what platform you are using.